# Change Bibliography Heading with My Current Setup

Tags: fonts, bibliographies, sectioning

I am writing a document of class book which has to follow a strict formatting rules. One of those rules forces me to redefine the headings of chapters, sections, subsections, TOC, LOF, LOT, and bibliography. In particular, the headings of chapters, TOC, LOF, LOT, and bibliography have to have the following font style:

- Large
- Bold
- Centered

I was able to do so for everything but Bibliography. Here is my minimal working example so that you can see how I was able to do that:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, oneside, 12pt]{book}



%%%%% Fonts and languages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}



%%%%% Page setup
\usepackage[top=1.5in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}

% Previewing margines (uncomment below)
%\usepackage{showframe} 

% Making document doublespaced
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% Centering chapters/sections and setting fonts
\usepackage{titlesec}           
 
\titlespacing{\chapter}
{0pt} % Default = 0pt
{-30pt} % Default = 50pt
{40pt} % Default = 40pt
 
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\large\bfseries\centering}
{\thechapter}
{10pt}
{}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalsize\bfseries\centering}
{\thesection}
{5pt}
{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalsize\bfseries\itshape\centering}
{\thesubsection}
{5pt}
{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalsize\bfseries\itshape}
{\thesubsubsection}
{5pt}
{}

\titleformat{\tableofcontents}
{\large\bfseries\centering}
{\tableofcontents}
{5pt}
{}

% Changing TOC
\addto\captionsenglish{% Replace "english" with the language you use
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {TABLE OF CONTENTS}%
}

\addto\captionsenglish{% Replace "english" with the language you use
    \renewcommand{\listfigurename}%
    {LIST OF FIGURES}%
}

\addto\captionsenglish{% Replace "english" with the language you use
    \renewcommand{\listtablename}%
    {LIST OF TABLES}%
}



% Setting font size for figure and table captions
\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{caption}

% Includes TOC, LOF, and LOT in TOC
\usepackage{tocbibind}



%%%%% Heather and Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}



%%%%% Links and references
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black, %for equations
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    citecolor=blue,
}



%%%%% Graphics
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[section]{placeins}



%%%%% Mathematics and science
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{siunitx} 

%COMMAND R
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}




\begin{document}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% FRONTMATTER                              %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\frontmatter

\input{frontmatter/titlepage}
\input{frontmatter/abstract}
\input{frontmatter/acknowledgments}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
%\listoftables



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% MAINMATTER                            %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\mainmatter

\input{mainmatter/introduction}
\input{mainmatter/background}
\input{mainmatter/methods}
\input{mainmatter/conclusion}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% BACKMATTER                            %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\backmatter

% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{backmatter/HUTref.bib}

\nocite{name1} 
\nocite{name2} 
\nocite{name3} 



\end{document}
```

**So, can someone please help me change the heading of Bibliography by making the font `\large\bfseries\centering` and changing the name from Bibliography to LIST OF REFERENCES?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it for me. Here is the source:
https://pairach.com/2012/10/10/rename-bibliography-to-references-in-latex/

**If the Babel package is used:**

*(I assume you have to change "english" to the language you use.)*

- For book or report class, add the following code in the preamble.

  `\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{LIST OF REFERENCES}}`
- For article class, add the following code in the preamble.

  `\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\refname}{LIST OF REFERENCES}}`

**If the Babel package is NOT used:**

- For book or report class, add the following code in the preamble.

  `\renewcommand{\bibname}{LIST OF REFERENCES}`
- For article class, add the following code in the preamble.

  `\renewcommand{\refname}{LIST OF REFERENCES}`